# Will image resizing increase the accuracy of an object detection model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I trained a custom object detection model using transfer learning and used the

> ssd_mobilenet_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu

for transfer learning, training and eval both went fine with both having a high accuracy of 90%, but when it comes to actually using it in real time it struggles to detect objects and it has a very low accuracy. I'm using it in taking screenshots of my PC screen which returns images of size:  2560 x 1080

The initial images I trained the model on where much smaller at 611 x 785, and I only trained it on around 50 images but each had around 20+ objects in different positions.

Should I train the model again using pictures of size 2560 x 1080 only to increase accuracy, or it wouldn't matter?

Comment: By using a higher resolution the models are able to bring out more complex features because there is more information in the context. However, increasing the resolution may not cause an increase in accuracy and a smaller size may be sufficient for your problem. In the end, it's all about testing :)

Comment: if you will always predict for size `2560 x 1080` then you could also train for size `2560 x 1080` but this may takes more time. But maybe you should rather get more examples for training

Comment: maybe you should ask on similar portal for [DataScience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)